# Marienbad game wrong XOR

Tags: c, artificial-intelligence, xor

I am actually working on a programming puzzle, I need to code an AI that always do the best current move to win the game.

The loser is the one who picks the last sticks.

Here is my board :

```
|  
|||  
|||||  
|
```

So I use the XOR operator on all my numbers to get the number of sticks I need to remove that give me : `1 XOR 3 XOR 5 XOR 1 = 6`

Now I do :
    1 XOR 6 = 7 (since it increased we won't select this case)
    3 XOR 6 = 5 (since it increased we won't select this case)
    5 XOR 6 = 3 (since it decreased we will reduce 5 to 3 by removing 2 sticks.

The problem is that I am playing in a "misere" version of the game where the loser if the one who take the last sticks and it seems that this method is perfect for the normal play where the winner is the one who take the last stick.

Could someone explain me what I should do in this case.

Comment: How would you solve the problem manually?
Implement that.

Answer (score 1):

The winning strategy isn't necessarily to XOR all the piles together and remove that many sticks from one pile. Instead, you want to choose a number of sticks to remove such that the XOR of all the piles is zero. For example, if you remove two sticks from the pile containing five sticks, the remaining XOR is 1 XOR 3 XOR 3 XOR 1 = 0.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I just edited my post to explain a little bit more the algorithm I am trying to use.